# How to position a rectangle overlay

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays

I try to realize the diagram of the attached photo. I am new to tikz and I have some trouble declaring the N-rectangle. I also have a problem to position the "decompose" arrow and also to change the position of the text in each rectangle. It's a lot of problems but every help will be precious,

Thank you in advance for your help,

Tom

[image]

```
% Required package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,shapes,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
 

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\sizein}{1}
\newcommand{\distin}{0.5}
\newcommand{\opacity}{0.8}
\newcommand{\xDist}{2.5}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {draw, fill=white, minimum size=\sizein cm},  
                    ]

\foreach \i   in {1,2,3}%
{
 
   \node   [box,below, left] at (\i*\distin,-\i*\distin) (x\i) {système linéaire \i};
     \node   [box,below, left,right=2cm of x\i] at (\xDist+\i*\distin,-\i*\distin) (y\i) {commande linéaire \i};

    
    \draw[->,dashed] (x\i.east) -- (y\i.west);
   
}
\node[fit=(x1)(x3)](fit1){};
\node[fit=(y1)(y3)](fit2){};
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror},black,very thick] (fit1.north west) --
  (fit1.south west) node[midway,left,align=left] (model) {sélection de commande};
  
  \draw[decorate,decoration=brace,black,very thick] (fit2.north east) --
  (fit2.south east) node[midway,right,align=left] (model1) {sélection de commande};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You put some braces to the left and right of your drawing. How should the decomposition arrow be positioned then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand how the braces you draw can fit into the image above, but maybe the following can help you.

I did the following:

- In order to avoid overlapping, I increased the vertical distance of the rectangles (by multiplication with the factor 1.6).
- Then, I shortened the dashed arrows by using the options `shorten <` and `shorten >`.
- I added another rectangle at position `5`, but I put an `\if` clause in the code, so that the text inside the node is `$N$` instead of `5`.
- Finally, I added some additional arrows that I aligned with the corners of the rectangles using anchors such as `.north east` etc. and the `xshift` option.

I deleted the code for the braces and the relevant TikZ packages. Feel free to put the code back, if you need it.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
    
% Required package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\sizein}{1}
\newcommand{\distin}{0.5}
%\newcommand{\opacity}{0.8}
\newcommand{\xDist}{2.5}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style = {draw, fill=white, minimum size=\sizein cm},  
]
                        
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3,5} {
        \node [box] at (\i*\distin,-1.6*\i*\distin) (x\i) {système linéaire \ifnum\i=5 $N$\else\i\fi};
        \node [box, right=2cm of x\i] at (\xDist+\i*\distin,-1.6*\i*\distin) (y\i) {commande linéaire \ifnum\i=5 $N$\else\i\fi};
    
        \draw[->, dashed, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm] (x\i.east) -- (y\i.west);
    }
    
    \draw[dashed, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm] (x3.south west) -- (x5.south west);
    \draw[dashed, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm] (x3.north east) -- (x5.north east);
    
    \draw[<->] ([xshift=-7mm]x1.west) -- ([xshift=-7mm]x5.west) node[midway, left] {décomposition};
    
\end{tikzpicture} 
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I couldn't imagine getting an answer so quickly. You are saving my life !!!